# Auth in li3 framework check(~ always authenticating

Tags: php, lithium

I've pretty much straight lifted my code from 
http://li3.me/docs/manual/auth/simple-authentication.md

in

```
if($user = Auth::check('customer', $this->request)) {
 //whatever
}
```

I'm trying to get a simple `Auth::check` in Lithium to fail when no user has logged in. Instead it seems to always perform a `User::first()` and return the first record in my Mysql users table where i would expect boolean `FALSE`.

[pastium](http://pastium.org/view/64344d054fad40852a57ca20804b29f7)

help appreciated,

Paul

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Auth::check($name, $request)` when you actually have something in the `$request` otherwise just use `Auth::check($name)`.

I've written another adapter instead of `Form` called `SaltedForm` because I'm not using a simple password hashing (see [pastium](http://pastium.org/view/2f054deee2f5552ac1e26c2c311ad668))

Comment: I figured the same call would always check for session data then query the db regardless. Great. thanks man!